# Mysterious Cookie expiration date `1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z`

Tags: cookies

I'm setting a cookie expiration (using Express) to a current date. But upon inspection in Chrome, the date is `1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z`.

In Firefox the Cookie's expiration date value is `session`.

Why is my cookie being set to this date? I'm thinking it is a bug, because Chrome is still sending the cookie, meaning it ACTUALLY ISN'T expired.

Comment: That date is 1 second before the UNIX timestamp epoch of 1970-01-01 00:00:00Z

Comment: Reworded my question.. I know what the date is. But it seems like a bug..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a cookie with 1969 as the expiration date mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51497459/what-does-a-cookie-with-1969-as-the-expiration-date-mean)

Answer (score 10):

> Unix time was started at the beginning of 1970, that means that -1 is in 1969. And that is a commonly used value for "unknown" if the expected value is usually positive. And for cookies MaxAge with a negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51497662/3892213

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're experiencing could be due to how you're setting the expiration date for the cookie in Express.

The date 1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z is essentially the **epoch time**, which is 0 in UNIX time.
This often happens when there's an issue parsing the date, or if you're accidentally setting it to a date that is in the past.

To properly set the expiration date for a cookie in Express, you can use the maxAge property or the expires property of the cookie object.

Also, regarding Firefox showing the expiration date as "session," this is expected behavior.
When you don't specify an expiration date for a cookie, it's considered a session cookie, meaning it will expire when the user closes their browser session.

Answer (score -3):

With express, you can use either *expire* or *maxAge* properties to set cookie expiry.

1. maxAge accepts relative time in milliseconds. e.g.

> res.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, { maxAge: milliseconds });

2. expire accepts a formatted date. e.g.

> res.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + milliseconds) });

refer to the expressjs documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie).