# What does a cookie with 1969 as the expiration date mean?

Tags: javascript, cookies

[image]

How can a cookie expire in 1969?

What does this mean?

Thanks,

Comment: Lots of places use the epoch date/time of 24:00 Dec 31 1969 / 00:00 Jan 1 1970 as their time-zero or default value for "unknown" or other pathological time.

Answer (score 26):

Unix time was started at the beginning of 1970, that means that `-1` is in 1969. And that is a commonly used value for "unknown" if the expected value is usually positive. And for cookies MaxAge with a negative value means that the cookie expires as soon as the browser gets closed:

Relevant section of the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.1):

> 5.2.2 [..] If delta-seconds is less than or equal to zero (0), let expiry-time
> be the earliest representable date and time.  Otherwise, let the
> expiry-time be the current date and time plus delta-seconds seconds.

Comment: "And for cookies MaxAge with a negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits." This does NOT seem to be true, at least in current Chrome. Running "document.cookie="name=value"" in the console sets a cookie with Expires in 1969. Restarting Chrome does NOT remove this cookie.

Comment: Maybe behaviour is browser dependent. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie says clearly "A zero or negative number will expire the cookie immediately." Hmm...

Comment: @peter actually my original answer was right, probably you missinterpret chromes output.